# Constructible $n$-gons

Tags: geometry, field-theory, galois-theory, geometric-construction

Let $\xi$ be the primitive root of unity.

If $n=5$, then the minimal polynomial of $xi$ over rationals would have degree $5-1=2^2$ which is a fermat prime so $5$-gon is constructible.

If $n=8$, then the min polynomial will have degree $8-1$ which is not a power of two so it is not constructible.

Is this all there is to whether $n$-gons can be constructible? Just minus one to the $n$ and see if it is a power of $2$?

Comment: The $8$-gon is constructible because we can construct the half of a given angle.

Comment: The $8-$gon is constructible. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296272/the-necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-regular-n-gon-to-be-constructible-b) for an answer.

Comment: Minimal polynomial of $8$th root of unity is $x^4+1$, which has degree $4$, not $8-1$, and is a power of $2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $n$-gon is constructible if and only if $n$ has the form

$$2^k\cdot p_1\cdot...\cdot p_m$$ , where $k$ is a non-negative integer and $p_1,...,p_m$ are distinct fermat primes.

You can also say : The $n$-gon is constructible if and only if $\phi(n)$ is a power of $2$. $\phi(n)$ is the euler-phi-function

The only known fermat primes are $3,5,17,257$ and $65537$. These are probably the only fermat-primes, but it is open whether there are more. The next possible fermat-prime is $F_{33}=2^{2^{33}}+1$ , having $$2,585,827,973$$ digits. It would be far larger than the currently largest known prime.

Comment: Can you show me a full working of n=8 please.

Comment: Also $\phi (n)=|Gal(f_n)|$ right? What is f_n?

Comment: $F_n$ is simply $2^{2^n}+1$, the $n$-th fermat-number

Comment: So how would you find Gal($2^{2^8}+1$)? Since that is what we want to work out right>

Comment: What do you mean with Gal, the galois-group ? $\phi(n)$ is the number of the elements of the set {$1,...,n-1$} being coprime to $n$. $F_n$ is a number, not a polynomial. And the criterion has nothing to do with galois-groups.

Comment: Is this what we do: n=8 so we need to find the min poly of $e^{2\pi i/8}$ which will obviously have degree 4. So 4 is a power of 2 so it is constructible

Comment: Yes, this is another way to attack the problem. And this degree is equal to $\phi(n)$, in your example $\phi(8)=4$. The $4$ elements $1,3,5,7$ are coprime to $8$.

Comment: So in genera, am i correct to say: If n is prime, then the deg of min polynomial will be n-1, if n-1 is a power of 2, then it is constructible. If n is not prime then, find the min poly of $e^{2\pi i/n}$ and see if the degree of this is a power of 2, if yes, then it is constructible.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the right way because the degree of the minimal polynomial is, as said , equal to $\phi(n)$, and $n$ is construcitble if and only if $\phi(n)$ and hence, the degree of the minimal polynomial, is a power of $2$.

Comment: OK thanks. One thing that scares me is what if the candidate for the min polynomial is so that it is hard to show it is irreducible over Q? Will there ever be a situation that would happen? Sometimes Eisenstein doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40554/discussion-between-peter-and-snowman).

Answer (score 2):

If $n=8$, the minimal polynomial has degree $\phi(8)=4$, so a regular octagon is constructible.

In general, a regular $n$-gon is constructible if and only if $n=2^kp_1\cdots p_m$ where the $p_j$ are distinct Fermat primes.

Answer (score 2):

No, it has to be a certain kind of "power of 2." For a regular polygon with a prime number $n\;$ of sides to be constructible using Euclid-approved methods, $n\;$ must be of the form $2^{2^m}+1\;$. The only ones known to date are

$\begin{array}{r|rrrrr}
m&0&1&2&3&4\\
n&3&5&17&257&65537
\end{array}$

Practically speaking, though, the 257-gon and 65537-gon are only theoretically constructible. (Both are indistinguishable from circles when drawn to fit a sheet of paper.)

Comment: The 65537-gon is not only theoretically constructible, Hermes has spent 10  years for an explicit construction of it. The resulting manuscript is 200 pages long....

Comment: @achille hui \\ I didn't mean that a construction didn't exist; what I meant was that if the construction of the 65537-gon were scaled down to a conveniently manageable size, the length of one of its sides would be less than the width of the point of whatever drawing instrument was being employed. By the way, where can I read up on Mr. Hermes's project?

Comment: According to wiki of  [65537-gon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537-gon), Hermes present the construction in the paper "Über die Teilung des Kreises in 65537 gleiche Teile". Nachrichten von der Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Göttingen, Mathematisch-Physikalische Klasse  (Göttingen) 3: 170–186. An online copy (in German) can be found [here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/resolveppn/GDZPPN002496585).

Comment: In Introduction To Geometry by  Coxeter , there are surprisingly simple constructions shown for a side of the regular 17-gon and 257-gon inscribed in a given circle. So it's plausible that there may a short  method for a side of  the 65537-gon  (given  a big enough circle !).